# Determine if Google Analytics Account/Property is under GA360 account via API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, analytics

Somewhat new to Google Analytics APIs. Ive pulled a list using the Analytics.Management.Accounts.list() method (AppScript/Sheets) and my 'admin' level user in bound to over a 100 accounts. I have  1000s of UA props returned as expected ie no GA4 properties, but I'm trying to delineate UA props that are under a 'standard' account VS a '360' account as it pertains to the UA properties returned.

I'm not sure there is an API 'hook' either @ account level or property level that I can use to make this decision. Maybe this can be derived from multiple logic branches, but not sure how to approach this logic flow.

Any insight appreciated.

Have tried several properties at both Account and Property level.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if UA property is under a Standard or 360 analytics account check the property's 'level' via the API. STANDARD || PREMIUM.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).